# Django restricting access to view for certain objects

Tags: python, django

I have some page that displays various players of a team. In the configuration you can switch between the teams, so if you put `TEAM_NAME = 'test'` it loads the test team obviously. The problem is, that if you put `TEAM_NAME = 'test2'`, it starts it up for that team, but I can still change the URL to switch between teams (while I should only be able to view the team I selected)

The URL looks like this:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/team/1/player/`, where `1` would be the first created team, which is `test`.

When I load the view, I would like to have some permission checks to see if the current view's team is the same as the team in the configuration.

This is the view:

```
class PlayerList(ListView):

    model = player_model
    template_name = 'player_list.html'

    def get_team(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_team'):
            team_id = self.kwargs.get('team_id')
            self._team = team_model.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('team_id'))
        return self._team

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context['team'] = self.get_team()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        return queryset.filter(team_id=self.kwargs.get('team_id'))

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PlayerList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that in `get` method to block/allow access:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    team_id = self.kwargs.get('team_id')
    team = team_model.objects.get(pk=team_id)
    if team.name != TEAM_NAME: 
        raise PermissionDenied
    else:
        return super(PlayerList, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Worked! Tweaked it a little, but thanks for this answer